# JSON to Mobile App Onsen

Tags: json, onsen-ui

I am new to the mobile app world and using the simple Onsen UI Framework.  I have a newsController calling for a list of posts in a category from my Wordpress site that works fine, but I cannot figure out how to call a json from a plugin called Events Espresso.

I can view the json file in my browser, but have no idea where to start putting it in Javascript to get it to my app.  Any help or direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an URL to the JSON file?

In your controller you can inject the `$http` service and then use `$http.get()` to fetch the data.

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('url/to/json/file').
    success(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status) {
      // Failed fetching the data!
    });
});
```

Comment: The address is:
mydomain.com/espresso-api/v1/events/public.pretty_json

Comment: Didn't seem to work unless I'm missing something in my html file.  I put what you wrote in my core.js and in html file I simply put:

<div class="app-page news-page" ng-controller="EventsController">

Of course I renamed MyController to EventsController and placed my url